# Run sudo commands without running the whole script with sudo (using a desktop launcher)

Tags: command-line, scripts, .desktop

My script is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo teamviewer --daemon enable
teamviewer
sudo teamviewer --daemon disable
```

It works fine on its own, and it requests my password with a terminal window. So, now I want to make a launcher for it. I have this in my `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Categories=Network;
Name=TeamViewer 12
Comment=Remote control and meeting solution.
Exec=gksu /path/here/Start.sh
Icon=teamviewer
```

That way it requests my password with a pop-up instead of a terminal window, but doing this runs the whole script with sudo, which is a problem, because TeamViewer refuses to start with sudo. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change to script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

teamviewer --daemon enable

sudo -u USERNAME teamviewer

teamviewer --daemon disable
```

This way you can execute `teamviewer` as USERNAME while still running the others as the sudo user, as you are running the script with `gksu`.

---

If you want an easy way to test it, run the following with `gksu`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Without 'sudo' -->" ; whoami

echo "With 'sudo -u USERNAME' -->" ; sudo -u USERNAME whoami
```

Comment: Yep. But you don't need the 1st and last `sudo` if the script is already being run via `gksu` (and it will have to be in order for the password to be requested once graphically).

Comment: That didn't work, not sure why

"Error: Could not create /root/.local/share/teamviewer12/logfiles"

"mkdir: cannot create directory '/root': Permission Denied"

"Error: InitDirs failed. (2)"

*Accidentally pressed enter before finishing the reply*

Comment: Alright, it worked once I replaced my username with root.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: @UltimatePOPCORNS But `sudo -u root teamviewer` is the same as `sudo teamviewer`, which you claimed does not work (and which sounds like a horrible security problem to me).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it to launch with my own username, as it writes to the /root directory for some reason.

Comment: @UltimatePOPCORNS you need `sudo -E` so that your environment variables are kept. Which of the `sudo` calls need that will depend on which of the commands is trying to write to `/root`.